# Bing search api foreign characters

Tags: bing, bing-api

I have used the bing image search API for a project but there is a problem with foreign characters in the search. It is actually a problem with the whole bing search, for example if you search for "bolån" (mortgage in Swedish) then you get image results for the rock singer Bolan.

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=bol%C3%A5n&FORM=HDRSC2

My question is if anyone has had similar problems and if you have found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

For images, there is a strong inclination to search for Rock singer's images for "bolan" term. You can try other term which is equivalent **hus inteckning** and you should get the correct results.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that bing seems to be very bad at understanding foreign characters like the swedish 'åäö'. Is there some setting to tell bing to actually use those characters and not changing them to the latin counterpart a-z? I mean, the difference between these two searches must be quite embarrassing for the second largest search engine:

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=bol%C3%A5n&FORM=HDRSC2
https://www.google.com/search?q=bol%C3%A5n&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_oIDRjMvbAhUnDsAKHWb2AikQ_AUICygC&biw=1895&bih=900